# Why isn't hibernate picking up database sequence for primary key column while inserting the records into the table?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, sequence

I was messing with my spring boot application. Wrote some code to insert few records into a table(called STARS) in my h2 database.

Here is the **schema.sql** for it:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS STAR;
CREATE TABLE STARS(
ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
LAST_NAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);

--STAR Sequence

drop sequence if exists STAR_SEQ;

create sequence STAR_SEQ
start with 500
increment by 100
minvalue 0
maxvalue 1000
nocycle;
```

***Entity Class***

```
package com.test.api.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GeneratorType;

@Entity
@Table(name="star")
public class Star {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ",sequenceName="STAR_SEQ",allocationSize=100)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="SEQ")
private Long id;
private String first_name;
private String last_name;
public Star() {}
public Star(String first_name,String last_name) {
    this.first_name=first_name;
    this.last_name=last_name;
}
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}
public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}
public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
}
public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}


}
```

***application.properties***

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
server.port=8081
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

***SpringBootApplication.java***

```
package com.test.api;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.test.api.model.Star;
import com.test.api.service.StarsService;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootapiApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
@Autowired
StarsService starService;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootapiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        starService.saveStar(new Star("Morgan","Freeman"));
        starService.saveStar(new Star("Brad","Pitt"));
        starService.saveStar(new Star("Tom","Cruise"));
        List<Star> allStars = starService.getAllStars();
        System.out.println("Size of elements:"+allStars.size());
        for(Star star:allStars)
            System.out.println(star.getFirst_name()+":"+star.getLast_name()+":"+star.getId());

    }

}
```

***Server Startup Log***

```
Hibernate: drop table star if exists
Hibernate: drop sequence if exists star_seq
Hibernate: create sequence star_seq start with 1 increment by 100
Hibernate: create table star (id bigint not null, first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255), primary key (id))
2019-11-16 23:43:19.733  INFO 13228 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2019-11-16 23:43:19.747  INFO 13228 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-11-16 23:43:20.245  WARN 13228 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-11-16 23:43:20.533  INFO 13228 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-11-16 23:43:20.957  INFO 13228 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2019-11-16 23:43:20.961  INFO 13228 --- [           main] com.test.api.SpringbootapiApplication    : Started SpringbootapiApplication in 6.785 seconds (JVM running for 8.566)
Hibernate: call next value for star_seq
Hibernate: call next value for star_seq
Hibernate: insert into star (first_name, last_name, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into star (first_name, last_name, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into star (first_name, last_name, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select star0_.id as id1_0_, star0_.first_name as first_na2_0_, star0_.last_name as last_nam3_0_ from star star0_
Size of elements:3
Morgan:Freeman:1
Brad:Pitt:2
Tom:Cruise:3
```

I was expecting the db sequence to get picked up and log should be printed like this instead:

```
Morgan:Freeman:500
Brad:Pitt:600
Tom:Cruise:700
```

Please help me understand. Thanks.

Comment: Probably because you defined the ID column as auto_increment.

Answer (score 0):

I have set the value of `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `create-drop`. This means that hibernate will create the schema for me using the entity definition. And it wasn't considering the `schema.sql` file at all. It was just using the configuration given in the entity class itself to create the sequence. In order for my table to retrieve the id from the sequence. I simply turned off the value of `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `none`. This will make the `schema.sql` to get executed without hibernate generating any database objects like tables/sequences.